# How to show an error message to the user in React when no data coming from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

In my **React APP**, I implemented an error message to occur when there are issues in getting the data from API. The goal is to show an error message instead of a list of the items which inform the user there is something wrong and to come back later.
Unfortunate I cannot make it works as it is not called the `showError()` and also no error in the console so I'm clueless to understand what can cause the issue to not make it works as should be.

The code I tried to do so is as follow:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {ListGroup, ListGroupItem, ListGroupItemHeading, Container} from "reactstrap";
import {getMoviesInfo} from "../../../Apis/MovieApi";
import {
  MdBook,
  MdVoiceChat,
  MdRecentActors,
  MdFlag,
  MdMovie,
  MdChildCare,
} from "react-icons/md";
import {FaAward, FaCalendarAlt, FaLanguage} from "react-icons/fa";
import {
  GiSandsOfTime,
  GiFountainPen,
  GiDirectorChair,
} from "react-icons/gi";
import Error from "../../../Components/Alert/Error";

export default class MovieDetails extends Component {
  state = {
    movieInfo: [],
    hasErrors: false,
    message: "Something went wrong, please refresh yours page or come back later",
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.onFetchInfo(this.props.movieID);
  }

  onFetchInfo = async movieID => {
    try {
      const info = await getMoviesInfo(movieID);

      console.log("GETTING IN DETAIL", info);

      this.setState({
        movieInfo: info,
      });

      return [];
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("onFetchInfo err: ", err);
      this.onShowErrorMessage(); // here is my error
    }
  };

  onShowErrorMessage = () => {
    this.setState({hasErrors: true, loading: false});
    setTimeout(this.onClearMessage, 5000);
  };
  // movieInfo && Object.keys(movieInfo).length !== 0 ?
  /* : (
    <div>{hasErrors && <Error message={message} />}</div>
    )*/
  render() {
    const {movieInfo, hasErrors, message} = this.state;
    return (
      <>
      <Container>
      {hasErrors && <Error message={message} />}
      </Container>

        <ListGroup className="list-info">
          <ListGroupItemHeading>{movieInfo.Title}</ListGroupItemHeading>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <MdBook />
            <span>{movieInfo.Plot}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <MdVoiceChat />
            <span>{movieInfo.Genre}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <GiDirectorChair />
            <span>{movieInfo.Director}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <MdRecentActors />
            <span>{movieInfo.Actors}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <GiFountainPen />
            <span>{movieInfo.Writer}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <MdFlag />
            <span>{movieInfo.Country}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <FaAward />
            <span>{movieInfo.Awards}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <FaCalendarAlt />
            <span>{movieInfo.Year}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <FaLanguage />
            <span>{movieInfo.Language}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <GiSandsOfTime />
            <span>{movieInfo.Runtime}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <MdMovie />
            <span>{movieInfo.totalSeasons}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <MdChildCare />
            <span>{movieInfo.Rated}</span>
          </ListGroupItem>
        </ListGroup>
      </>
    );
  }
}

MovieDetails.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.any,
  info: PropTypes.shape({
    Title: PropTypes.string,
    Actors: PropTypes.string,
    Awards: PropTypes.string,
    Country: PropTypes.string,
    Genre: PropTypes.string,
    Language: PropTypes.string,
    Plot: PropTypes.string,
    Year: PropTypes.string,
    Runtime: PropTypes.string,
    totalSeasons: PropTypes.string,
    Rated: PropTypes.string,
    Writer: PropTypes.string,
    Director: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  movieID: PropTypes.string,
};
```

When there is an error the `catch()`it is showing me the `console.log()` but is not calling the function to show the error message it is ignoring that and that cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You could conditionally ask with JSX if the array or object is empty - `console.log("what ever you want") or render( <WhatEverYouWant /> )`

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correct the reason your function inside catch block is not running because try..catch works synchronously. If an exception happens in “scheduled” code, like in setTimeout, then try..catch won’t catch it:

```
try {

} catch (e) {
  alert( "won't work" );
  setTimeout(function() {
    noSuchVariable; // script will die here
  }, 1000);
}
```

That’s because the function itself is executed later, when the engine has already left the try..catch construct.

To catch an exception inside a scheduled function, try..catch must be inside that function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  try {
    noSuchVariable; // try..catch handles the error!
  } catch {
    alert( "error is caught here!" );
  }
}, 1000);
```

You can get detailed information about working of try..catch.. on this [blog](https://javascript.info/try-catch)